# How generate Point struct in range on Rust

Tags: rust

I can't understand how to write trait for generating Point in some range.

I try to use `rand::Rng` for generate random values for Point struct (for coordinates in minesweeper).

I use this site [Generate Random Values - Rust Cookbook](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/algorithms/randomness.html)
And it fine worked for ranges for simple data types. Also, worked examples with Point.

Could someone provide example of code and some explanation about traits for Uniform for Point struct?

```
use rand::Rng;
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform};


fn main() {
  let width: u8 = 15; let height: u8 = 15;
  let mine_count: u8 = 40;
  let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
  let ranger = Uniform::from(0..width);
  for _i in 0..=mine_count{
    let rand_point: Point = ranger.sample(&mut rng);
    println!("Random Point: {:?}", rand_point);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

impl Distribution<Point> for Uniform<Point> {
  fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> Point {
    let (rand_x, rand_y) = rng.gen();
    Point {
      x: rand_x,
      y: rand_y,
    }
  }
}
```

```
   Compiling my-project v0.1.0 (/home/runner/SyntaxTest)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Point: SampleUniform` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:56:30
    |
56  | impl Distribution<Point> for Uniform<Point> {
    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `SampleUniform` is not implemented for `Point`

note: required by a bound in `Uniform`
   --> /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.8.5/src/distributions/uniform.rs:179:23
    |
179 | pub struct Uniform<X: SampleUniform>(X::Sampler);
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Uniform`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Point: SampleUniform` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:57:30
    |
57  |   fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> Point {
    |                              ^^^^^ the trait `SampleUniform` is not implemented for `Point`

note: required by a bound in `Uniform`
   --> /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.8.5/src/distributions/uniform.rs:179:23
    |
179 | pub struct Uniform<X: SampleUniform>(X::Sampler);
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Uniform`
```

Comment: It's exactly what the compiler says, `SampleUniform` is not implemented for Point; if it were then you could impl Distribution for Uniform<Point>; So if you do that then the impl Distribution would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your code has no concept of what is a distribution of Points.
If you look at the signature of the Uniform struct, its generic has to implement the `SampleUniform` trait. According to the docs, the `SampleUniform` trait defines the Sampler type that should be used in order to generate random distributions.
So, when you write this:

```rust
impl Distribution<Point> for Uniform<Point> {
  fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> Point {
    let (rand_x, rand_y) = rng.gen();
    Point {
      x: rand_x,
      y: rand_y,
    }
  }
}
```

When you call `Uniform::from(0..width)`, you are also defining a sampler for u8 values, which is not what you want in the end. What you want (judging by your code) is to generate a random distribution of points between a min, say Point { x: 0, y: 0 }, and a maximum value, which could be another point, but it could also be defined as a range, a delta, an area, etc. The idea is to be able to write something like this:

```rust
let ranger = Uniform::from(
        Point::default()..Point {
            x: width,
            y: height,
        },
    );
```

Where `Point::default()` is the origin.
To solve your problem you need to be able to tell the rand crate what exactlyis it that you mean when you ask for that distribution of Points.
To keep your code as is, you could rewrite it like this:

```rust
use rand::distributions::uniform::{SampleUniform, UniformInt, UniformSampler};
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform};
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let width: u8 = 4;
    let height: u8 = 5;
    let mine_count: u8 = 40;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let ranger = Uniform::from(
        Point::default()..Point {
            x: width,
            y: height,
        },
    );
    for _i in 0..=mine_count {
        let rand_point: Point = ranger.sample(&mut rng);
        println!("Random Point: {:?}", rand_point);
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Default)]
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

struct UniformPoint {
    x: UniformInt<u8>,
    y: UniformInt<u8>,
}

impl SampleUniform for Point {
    type Sampler = UniformPoint;
}

impl UniformSampler for UniformPoint {
    type X = Point;

    fn new<B1, B2>(low: B1, high: B2) -> Self
    where
        B1: rand::distributions::uniform::SampleBorrow<Self::X> + Sized,
        B2: rand::distributions::uniform::SampleBorrow<Self::X> + Sized,
    {
        let low = *low.borrow();
        let high = *high.borrow();
        UniformPoint {
            x: UniformInt::<u8>::new_inclusive(low.x, high.x - 1),
            y: UniformInt::<u8>::new_inclusive(low.y, high.y - 1),
        }
    }

    fn new_inclusive<B1, B2>(low: B1, high: B2) -> Self
    where
        B1: rand::distributions::uniform::SampleBorrow<Self::X> + Sized,
        B2: rand::distributions::uniform::SampleBorrow<Self::X> + Sized,
    {
        let low = *low.borrow();
        let high = *high.borrow();
        UniformPoint {
            x: UniformInt::<u8>::new_inclusive(low.x, high.x),
            y: UniformInt::<u8>::new_inclusive(low.y, high.y),
        }
    }

    fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> Self::X {
        Point {
            x: self.x.sample(rng),
            y: self.y.sample(rng),
        }
    }
}

impl Distribution<Point> for Point {
    fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> Point {
        let (rand_x, rand_y) = rng.gen();
        Point {
            x: rand_x,
            y: rand_y,
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to implement the `Distribution` trait any longer, since `Uniform::from` only requires that your struct implements `SampleUniform`.

The trick here is that each field in Point needs to be generated from a distribution of values. Since you can use `UniformInt::<u8>...` to generate those distributions, then all you need is an accessory struct that can as a placeholders for those distributions.

Notice that now, when you call `ranger.sample()` you're actually making two calls. One to x.sample and one to y.sample.

This results in a neat API, where you can still use the ranger as you did before without any modifications.
Another solution would be to keep your u8 distribution and create your random points by doing:

```rust
for _i in 0..=mine_count {
        let rand_point = Point {
            x: ranger.sample(&mut rng),
            y: ranger.sample(&mut rng),
        }
        println!("Random Point: {:?}", rand_point);
    }
```

This way you don't need to implement anything, but it is also less fun.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement `Distribution<Point>` for `Uniform<u8>`, not `Uniform<Point>`:

```
use rand::Rng;
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform};


fn main() {
  let width: u8 = 15; let height: u8 = 15;
  let mine_count: u8 = 40;
  let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
  let ranger = Uniform::from(0..width);
  for _i in 0..=mine_count{
    let rand_point: Point = ranger.sample(&mut rng);
    println!("Random Point: {:?}", rand_point);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

impl Distribution<Point> for Uniform<u8> {
  fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> Point {
    let (rand_x, rand_y) = rng.gen();
    Point {
      x: rand_x,
      y: rand_y,
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=033410d5edabdb49fbd6e5a5a1b6d081)